# Computer can't reach to 192.168.0.1

Tags: networking, router, dns

Everything was fine yesterday, but tonight my computer can't access internet though eternet/Power Line Communication (PLC).

My other equipment are doing fine on wifi, I just can't reach my box (192.168.0.1) from my computer (but I can from other equipment)

Windows is in French, but it says something about "no valid ip configuration"

I disconnected everything/reconnected in all possible order.

I tried in order (and reboot at the end):

```
netsh winsock reset 
netsh winhttp reset proxy 
netsh winhttp reset tracing 
netsh winsock reset catalog 
netsh int ipv4 reset catalog 
netsh int ipv6 reset catalog
```

I also tried to change my DNS, auto, google's one, box one.

Here is my ipconfig

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig

Configuration IP de Windows


Carte Ethernet Ethernet :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::143c:59c6:88bd:5429%14
   Adresse d’autoconfiguration IPv4 . . . : 169.254.84.41
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :

Carte Ethernet Ethernet 2 :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::45cc:6b1f:9c75:a04f%2
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.20.10.6
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 172.20.10.1

Carte Tunnel Connexion au réseau local* 2 :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :

Carte Tunnel isatap.{1575B7B8-39CE-4B8C-8948-E86EE5D975A9} :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :

Carte Tunnel isatap.{CCBDE231-2F6A-4B31-BDBD-057B277B3832} :

   Statut du média. . . . . . . . . . . . : Média déconnecté
   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
```

I don't have a lenghty enought ethernet cable to direclty connect it to my computer, nor any wifi key for further testing. Will grab one tomorow.

EDIT: Currently using my mobile shared connection, if it appears on the ipconfig report and trouble you

Comment: Being in french i'm not sure but it looks like your computer is not getting an ip.  169 is a self assigned but i dont what Ethernet 2 is used for on your machine.

Comment: Powerline adapters are notorious for going bad, so that would be the first thing I suspect to have failed. Although you don't have an Ethernet cable long enough to reach the router, it would be wise to move your PC closer to the router or buy a longer one to ensure that it's not the network adapter.  You're getting a 169.254.X.X which means your NIC failed to communicate with a DHCP server so it auto assigned itself that address. Is adapter 2 the mobile shared connection you've mentioned, because that's a valid class B private IP.

Comment: Try resetting the powerline adapters.

Comment: The pladaptee is high grade one, new. And yes ethernet 2 is my phone. Tomorrow i get the cable

Comment: Most powerline ethernet adapters have a light that tells you whether they're talking to a local device and a light that tells you whether or not they're talking to a remove device.

Comment: Even the best devices can have their communication interrupted. Pull them out, wait a minute, plug them in again.

Comment: Your computer doesn't have a NIC configured for the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet.  Ethernet 1 is on the Microsoft default network, and Ethernet 2 is on the 172.20.10.0, not 192.168.0.0.  What do you use each network connection for?

Comment: LOL. Reseting the power line adapter instantly fixed the problem... i reseted only two out of three before and didnt went through the last one since i thought it wouldnt fix it... thanks a lot @DavidPostill . Devil is in the details

Comment: @Mayerz You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) - you should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @DanielB I already tried that with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reseting the power line adapter instantly fixed the problem... There was a little hole for reseting it.

Thanks @DavidPostill